# Webpack not being recognized after updates

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, webpack, laravel-mix

In my laravel app, after updating to [laravel-mix v4](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/releases/tag/v4.0.0), when I run `npm run watch`, I get the error:

> webpack not installed,
>
> consider installing it using  npm install
>   --save-dev webpack

Even when Webpack v4.33.0 is clearly installed & available in my node_modules. Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
    "laravel-mix": "^4.0.16",
    "webpack": "^4.33.0"
  }
}
```

Here is my webpack.mix.js:

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js','public/js/app.js')
.browserSync({
    proxy: 'app.test',
    notify: false,
    open: true,
    port: 8080
})
.options({
    extractVueStyles: OUTPUTCSS + 'app.css'
});
```

This wasn't an issue prior to updating my `laravel-mix` to v4, what seems to be the issue?

**--- UPDATE ---**

Here is the `npm debug log`:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'run', 'watch' ]
2 info using npm@6.2.0
3 info using node@v10.9.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prewatch', 'watch', 'postwatch' ]
5 info lifecycle @~prewatch: @
6 info lifecycle @~watch: @
7 verbose lifecycle @~watch: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle @~watch: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/main_user/projects/test_project/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin
9 verbose lifecycle @~watch: CWD: /Users/main_user/projects/test_project
10 silly lifecycle @~watch: Args: [ '-c', 'npm run development -- --watch' ]
11 silly lifecycle @~watch: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle @~watch: Failed to exec watch script
13 verbose stack Error: @ watch: `npm run development -- --watch`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:304:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:182:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:961:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:250:5)
14 verbose pkgid @
15 verbose cwd /Users/main_user/projects/test_project
16 verbose Darwin 18.6.0
17 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "watch"
18 verbose node v10.9.0
19 verbose npm  v6.2.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error @ watch: `npm run development -- --watch`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the @ watch script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: In these cases I just remove node_modules altogether and do another `npm install` from scratch

Comment: @Chris no dice :(

Comment: @Chris check updated question, added debug log

Comment: Ran into this myself after trying to create a minimal repro for another bug. Here's the github issue: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/9242

Comment: I just ran into this problem, and i have to use an old version of webpack to temporary fix it. from "webpack": "^4.33.0" to "webpack": "4.12.2".

Comment: Based on [this issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli/issues/944), this seems to be a problem of incorrect reporting of missing dependencies. I guess you should check that you have all the dependencies installed. I was using a missing plugin in webpack.config.js and was getting the same error.

Answer (score 2):

Found a similar issue over at [webpack/webpack-cli#944](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli/issues/944)

this appears to happen when the webpack.config.js module `require()`s a missing module or requires are not installed using npm

Answer (score 0):

You can also try change `webpack-cli` version to `2.1.3`
Verify you are not using any deprecated plugins. I had to change GlobCopyWebpackPlugin to CopyWebpackPlugin